# Is combining two ggplots with same X vector poor practice/style?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Edit Note: My original minimal working example did not accurately reflect my question. Two answers were posted that are great references, but were misguided by my example. For more info, see my comment on r2evan's answer. I've since edited the example. Thanks!

---

I recently found myself in a position where I wanted to merge two ggplot objects. `plot1` and `plot2` had the same `x` values, and I just wanted to take the `y` values from `plot2` and throw them onto `plot1`'s backbone.

It's super simple, so I assumed something like it already existed, but I couldn't find anything. Considering how well-developed R is, I assume either (1) this does exist, and I just haven't found it, or (2) what I'm doing is poor practice/style. Could you let me know which one it is and, if the latter, why should I avoid doing this?

(Actual situation: I have a method in a package that returns a nicely-formatted ggplot object. I want to run that method with a bunch of different objects, but combine the output onto one plot. I would use this helper function to accumulate all of the plots into one)

---

**Minimal working example**

Okay, so not a fully-working example anymore, I suppose. Assume that the "mysteryObject" class has been defined, and the `plotMystery` method works on those objects and makes a dataframe with constant x values, but different y values based on the `id` field.

```
object1 <- new("mysteryObject", id=1)
plot1 <- plotMystery(object1)
plot1
```

[image: plot1]

```
object2 <- new("mysteryObject", id=2)
plot2 <- plotMystery(object2)
plot2
```

[image: plot2]

```
combine_plots <- function(ggplot1, ggplot2, color = black) {
    return(
        ggplot1 +
            geom_line(aes(x = ggplot2$data[,1], y = ggplot2$data[,2]), color = color)  
    )
}

plot_combined <- combine_plots(plot1, plot2, color = "red")
plot_combined
```

[image: plot_combined]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do much, just combine the data and provide a "source"-type field that `ggplot` can use to split/group/color based on.

For instance, your data and the combined data:

```r
dat1 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5), y = c(1,2,3,4,5))
dat2 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5), y = c(1,2,9,16,25))

datn <- rbind.data.frame(
  transform(dat1, source = "dat1"),
  transform(dat2, source = "dat2")
)
datn
#    x  y source
# 1  1  1   dat1
# 2  2  2   dat1
# 3  3  3   dat1
# 4  4  4   dat1
# 5  5  5   dat1
# 6  1  1   dat2
# 7  2  2   dat2
# 8  3  9   dat2
# 9  4 16   dat2
# 10 5 25   dat2
```

And the plot, no grob-combinations required:

```r
ggplot(data = datn, aes(x = x, y = y, color = source)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image: sample grouped data]

There are numerous ways to further control this, including (1) defining which colors are available for groups/colors/facets, etc; (2) presence and aesthetics of the legend; (3) just about anything else (since it's `ggplot2`).

Comment: Yes! This absolutely works for most cases. The reason I didn't immediately do this is that I don't have direct access to the data. I'll modify my question to be more clear. I have a method that takes in an object-->makes a dataframet-->plots the data. Your method will work for me if I split my method into--(1) that takes object-->makes dataframe and (2) data frame-->formatted plot. That way, I can use method (1) to make dataframes, merge those, and use (2) to plot. It requires me to change my infrastructure, but I bet that's the way I should've done it from the beginning, anyways. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes, it always depends on your workflow. I find benefits from completely separating data-collection/aggregation from plotting when possible. That is, create/collect/munge data all at once, for 1-to-n frames, and then worry about creating 1-to-n (or just 1) plots from those frames. It's a different mindset and flow. This answer is not well tuned to creating plots on-the-fly, in which case you'll likely need to research combining grobs; and even then, I believe you'll end up grabbing data or components from one and adding to another ... a post-hoc version of this.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the data, then go to a long format which can all be done using `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5), y = c(1,2,3,4,5))
data2 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5), y = c(1,2,9,16,25))
data %>% 
full_join(data2, by = "x") %>% 
gather(key, value, -x) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = x, y = value, group = key, color = key)) + 
geom_line()
```

Comment: This doesn't work if there are `x`s in one that are not in the other.

Comment: Updated it to use a `full_join` as opposed to `right_join`. That should do it.

Comment: Yes, and you'll also run into `NA` values in the resulting data that are *added* and not part of the original data. If the statement *"had the same x values"* is held perfectly-verbatim, then this will work, but since you're `gather`ing the data anyway, might as well be a little safer and just `rbind` them together. I believe (additional `NA`s notwithstanding) your data post `gather` and my `datn` are functionally equivalent.

Comment: Said differently: I'm being OCD with adding data when it isn't necessary. If by chance one frame is *slightly* different than the other, a join operation starts *changing the data*, something to avoid. I thought the `rbind` method was effecting the same structure for a singular `ggplot` call (on that we perfectly agree).